# Fine-Uploader: Getting the original triggered element (clicked, or dropped)

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I have one fineuploader instance, and installed a number of drop targets and buttons.

The way I'm arranging this is similar to Google Drive's upload feature, where there is one centralized upload box that lists all the files in progress, and on completion, I would like to do some DOM manipulation on the original triggered elements (drop target, or button), and put a preview, and some details in it.

To do the DOM manipulation, I would like to get the original triggered element.

To make this more clear, here is how I initialized the drag and drop element:

```
    $('.drop-zone').fineUploaderDnd({
        classes: {
            dropActive: "cssClassToAddToDropZoneOnEnter"
        }
    })
    .on('processingDroppedFiles', function(event) {
        //TODO: display some sort of a "processing" or spinner graphic
    })
    .on('processingDroppedFilesComplete', function(event, files, dropTarget) {
        //TODO: hide spinner/processing graphic

        $gallery_upload.fineUploaderS3('addFiles', files); //this submits the dropped files to Fine Uploader
    });
```

Here is how I initialized the button:

```
$gallery_upload.fineUploaderS3({
    ...

    extraButtons: [{
        element: $(".pdf-button"),
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ["jpg"]
        }
    }],
    ...
```

I was reading the documentation on fineuploader, but don't find any variables that explain about the possibilities of this.

I was wondering if this is possible, and if so, please kindly give me some assistance.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Thomas

==============================================

So from the start, I shouldn't have used the separate module: 
    $('.drop-zone').fineUploaderDnd({...

Now, I have modified my code for Dnd to the following, and then, Ray's solution will work nicely with it:

```
$gallery_upload.fineUploaderS3({
    dragAndDrop: {
        extraDropzones: [ $('.drop-zone') ]
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`onValidate` event handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#validate) is passed an `HTMLElement` pointing to the upload button associated with the file.  You can also use [the `getButton` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getButton) to find which button is associated with a particular file, given the file's ID.

Fine Uploader also adds a `qqDropTarget` property on to a dropped `File` object.  The value of this property is the drop zone element that processed the dropped file.  This is only done with the integrated DnD (Fine Uploader UI) drop tool (not the standalone).  For some reason, this is not documented, I'll have to try to remember why.  If this was simply an oversight, I'll add this to the documentation.

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for the quick reply.  The getButton() API seems to work, and I'm using that on the "onComplete()" callback.  I got a separate problem for this, but the original problem of this question is solved.  I'll raise a separate question on that.

For this question though, I still have one problem.  I do note that you have the qqDropTarget property.  However, would there be any ways of getting this only during the callback onComplete()?

I'm not too certain on how I can link from the onComplete, to the original dropped target.

Would be great if you can give me some advice.  Thanks Ray!

Comment: One more thing to add, there is also a "Paste Zone" target.  Any API to grab this off as well?

Comment: You can always get the `File`, given the file's ID via [the `getFile` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getFile).  Remember that the `File` object contains the `qqDropTarget` property.

Comment: We only allow one paste zone per Fine Uploader instance, so that should be easy to determine.  If there is no button or drop zone associated with the file, it was either passed in via the API, or pasted in.

Comment: Hi Ray, I'm using the JQuery S3 version of the latest Fine Uploader.  Please see the [link here](http://beamstyle.com.hk/download/fu.png).  I did a console.log in oncomplete.  I did get the file, but the qqDropTarget is not inside.  Did I misunderstand something, or used the wrong version of fineuploader which does not support this parameter as you said?

Comment: I see you are using the standalone DnD module.  As I mentioned in my answer, the `qqDropTarget` property is only added to files by Fine Uploader UI when using the integrated file drop support.  If you are using the standalone DnD module, you'll need to annotate the `File` objects yourself.  You can see [how Fine Uploader UI does this with the integrated drop module for reference](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/671e0840f8ad16ce2ea9a6bcdc895e90a090ab14/client/js/uploader.api.js#L136).

Comment: ...also, it's not clear why you aren't just using the integrated file drop support.  Unless there is a very good reason for this (there usually is not) then just use the integrated file drop support instead of the standalone DnD module.

Comment: Ah that makes things clear.  Actually the reason I didn't use that option was because I didn't notice this was possible from the documentation.  I used the method above because that was the only example I could find in the document.  But after some trial and errors, I got it to work.  I'm gonna post my set up of the DnD above, for those who in the future who face the same problem as I had.  Thanks for the help Ray!